# jQuery offset always return 0 on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I am trying to make an animated svg. I need to calculate current svg block position using jQuery('TargetID').offset();

But jQuery offset always return 0.

```
var id = getElementById('secondItem');
var offset = $(id).offset();
```

Offset working fine on Google chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `var offset = $('#secondItem').offset()`?

Comment: @sean why would that return anything different? It's the same element

Comment: @charlietfl `getElementById()` is a document method. Calling it by itself will result in an error